# External table from compressed parquet files (e.g., gz.parquet) in Hive/Impala

Tags: hive, impala, parquet, external-tables

How do I create an external table from a collection of compressed parquet files (e.g., gz.parquet) in Hive/Impala?

Answer (score 1):

If the folder has _metadata file and is not partitioned then you can use this SQL command:-

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tablename LIKE PARQUET 'hdfs:///_metadata' STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'hdfs://folder_location_of_parquet'; .
```